# ng-click within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, I have an array of colors that have a `title` and a `type`. I display all the colors as a list.

Now I would like to add a menu that allows the user to select to only show the colors of a particular `type`. For this purpose, I have another array that contains colortypes. This is also displayed as a list.

Now I would like to click on a colortype to reduce the list of colors to only those colors that have the selected `color.type`. For that I use a filter:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="color in colors | filter:search">
        {{ color.title }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

With a manual list of colortypes, it all works fine:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="" ng-click="search.type = 'primary';">
            Primary
        </a>
    </li>               
</ul>
```

However, when I use an array of colortypes as described above, the click does nothing:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="colortype in colortypes">
        <a href="" ng-click="search.type = '{{ colortype.title }}';">
            {{ colortype.title }}
        </a>
    </li>               
</ul>
```

I suppose this has something to do with the ng-click being placed within the ng-repeat (or maybe the scope of the `=` assignment)? How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ngClick` directive you specify not JS code, but expression.

So you can just use `<a href="" ng-click="search.type = colortype.title">` and it will work (note: no interpolation by `{{}}`)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Even with `search.type = 'primary'` it will not work if it is placed *within* `ng-repeat`. As I said, I am thinking it might be a scope problem?

Comment: Initialize `$scope.search = {}` in your controller, making `search` object available to child scopes created by `ngRepeat`. Just tested on plnkr and it works (I can create plnkr again if you still can't do that).

Do not forget, that AngularJS use `prototype inheritance`, so if there is `search` object in parent scope, your expression will use it. If no, then it will create new object in each child scopes, created by `ngRepeat`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ng-repeat` creates child scopes, `ng-click` is referencing the child scope rather than the controller's scope. Here are two options to deal with this.

**1)** A quick and dirty way is to access the original scope using `$parent`.

Change your `ng-click` to something like this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="$parent.search.type = colortype.title;">
    {{ colortype.title }}
</a>
```

[See $parent solution in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxn2hzne/2/)

This approach can break down if the above template is nested or becomes nested. Then you would need to access the controller scope with `$parent.$parent...` etc.

**2)** A better approach is to create a function on the controller's scope which returns a reference to the scope.  Because of [prototypal inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance), you can access the controller scope functions from the child scope.

```
function ColorCtrl($scope) {      
    $scope.getColorCtrlScope = function() {
         return $scope;   
    }
    .....
 <a href="#" ng-click="getColorCtrlScope().search.type = colortype.title;">
     {{ colortype.title }}
 </a>
```

[See better solution in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxn2hzne/3/)